# FrameLayout doesn't fill CoordinatorLayout after GONE a view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout

Here is my main layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_con"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="#cc0000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Close"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/green"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

After event `onClick on TextView` (id/close), I set `visibility for RelativeLayout` (id/top_con) to `GONE`. But `FrameLayout` (contain a recycler view) still `keep their height`, and there's a white space (white is background color of CoordinatorLayout ) at bottom of sreen.
What is problem and how can fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: after setting the visibility to gone, just invalidate the frame layout like this framelayout.invalidate();

Comment: @balajikoduri it doesn't work. I tried before

Comment: try this : framelayout.requestLayout()

Comment: @balajikoduri still not work. :)

Comment: Try adding `android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"` to the frame.